# subtracting result values from each other

Tags: php

I have all working fine and now wish to add this statement which now displays fine but I need it to subtract the first from the second and display that as the \n

```
echo "$num_rows HyperGrid User(s)\n";echo $this->db->count_all('GridUser WHERE Online = "True" AND Login > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400)');?><br/>
```

TIA
John

Comment: What do you mean? Subtraction in PHP is done with the minus operator. `$a=9; $b=4; $c=$a-$b;` will set `$c` to 5.

Comment: I get a value for the first statement then I need to subtract that from the second statement and print the result I am not a php coder as of yet.. this looks at a MySQL database to get its results

Comment: So `$num_rows` holds the total number of users and your count_all query gets the users online in the last 86400s?

Comment: yes.. what i need to do id take the count_all query and subtract the $num_rows from it then display the result

Comment: @Cloneu Inglewood you use the minus operator to subtract values: echo "$thisValue - $thatValue"; it is that simple. Do this and then update your answer with what you have tried. If you are learning php look at some tutorials: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/operators.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$online_users = $this->db->countAll(...);
echo $online_users - $num_rows;
```

But please read a book on PHP and/or programming in general.

Comment: I have been reading though have just started with php.. that fix did not work or I did something wrong with it.. but TY for your help..33 HyperGrid User(s) with mine this is the display i have on the webpage.. i need to subtract the first 3 from the second 3 and would get 0 in this case  if the online users was say 5 and the rows were say 3 then i should get 2 as a display result

Comment: Thank You after further reading I was able to accomplish it with your help  Kudos to Edward